# How can I coerce a TypeScript type based on an enum?

Tags: typescript

I have:

```
export const SupportedPrograms = [
  'program1',
  'program2',
  ...
] as const;

export type ProgramType = typeof SupportedPrograms[number];
```

And I have:

```
      const actionType: string = 'p1'
      const REDIRECT_MAP = {
        p1: 'program1',
        p2: 'program2'
      };
      const redirectType: ProgramType = REDIRECT_MAP[
        actionType
      ] as unknown as ProgramType;
```

So I want to convert the `actionType`, which is a string, to be `redirectType`, which needs to be of `ProgramType`.

But this Is giving me an error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ p1: string; p2: string; }'.
```

I thought the `unknown` would allow it, but no dice. Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't use types like `string` when you actually care about string literal types, but if you are going to assert things you also need to assert `actiontype as keyof typeof REDIRECT_MAP` otherwise you will have an implicit any error.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJq7Dm).  Does that address your question fully?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I think this might work. Please put an answer up if you can

Comment: I tend to write  ̴l̴̵̴̶̴̵̴o̴̵̴̶̴̵̴n̴̵̴̶̴̵̴g̴̵̴̶̴̵̴w̴̵̴̶̴̵̴i̴̵̴̶̴̵̴n̴̵̴̶̴̵̴d̴̵̴̶̴̵̴e̴̵̴̶̴̵̴d̴̵̴̶̴̵̴  thorough answers so I prefer to be sure the approach meets the needs of the OP before writing.  Could you check to see if you can upgrade "I think this might work" to "this works"?  If not, someone else can post something.  Good luck!

Comment: Yup - absolutely! It works (for those in the future that might come across this). Thanks @jcalz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need ProgramType in the end, you can use something like this:

```
type RedirectMap = { [key: string]: ProgramType };

const REDIRECT_MAP: RedirectMap = {
    p1: 'program1',
    p2: 'program2'
};
```

[image]